# How to transform (standardize) data within categories in a single data frame in R?

Tags: r

I need to scale values only within certain categories. Essentially I have a data.frame with individuals, years, and several predictors.

| Individual | Year | Uplift |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2013 | 0.76280999 |
| A | 2013 | 1.01930776 |
| A | 2015 | 0.00000000 |
| B | 2011 | 0.78427964 |
| B | 2013 | 0.00000000 |
| B | 2013 | 1.37627043 |

I need to scale my predictors within each individual and year, in other words standardize Individual A year 2013, Individual A year 2015 and so on for 33 individuals and 86 thousand rows. Not wishing to do this in separate data frames for each individual and year combination, I tried to use a dplyr solution

`library("dplyr")`

`data %>%`

`group_by(Individual, Year) %>%`

`mutate(data, std_uplift= scale(uplift) %>%`

`ungroup()))`

Naturally, this throws an error:

> Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.

> x Input `..1` can't be recycled to size 1100.

> i Input `..1` is `data`.

> i Input `..1` must be size 1100 or 1, not 83670.

> i The error occurred in group 1: Individual = "A", year = "2013".

I don't understand how to fix the error, as it seems to be trying to shove data from all individuals into a single group, but I am guessing that there is a better way to scale data given categories. How can I make this work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library("dplyr")
df <- tribble(
  ~Individual,  ~Year,  ~Uplift,
"A", 2013, 0.76280999, 
"A", 2013, 1.01930776, 
"A", 2015, 0.00000000, 
"B", 2011, 0.78427964, 
"B", 2013, 0.00000000, 
"B", 2013, 1.37627043)

df %>% 
  mutate(std_Uplift = as.numeric(scale(Uplift))) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Individual  Year Uplift std_Uplift[,1]
  <chr>      <dbl>  <dbl>          <dbl>
1 A           2013  0.763          0.190
2 A           2013  1.02           0.653
3 A           2015  0             -1.18 
4 B           2011  0.784          0.229
5 B           2013  0             -1.18 
6 B           2013  1.38           1.30
```

Comment: `scale` returns a `matrix` and that could the reason that the column names have `[,1]`.  May be you could wrap with `as.numeric(scale`